# Macro to re-arrange columns based on array throws error

Tags: excel, vba

I have been looking for a macro like this for a long time.

The macro throws a 1004 error and the `Columns(l + 1).Insert` is highlighted in yellow

```
This selection is not valid

Copy and past areas cannot overlap unless they'er the same size and shape
```

There are 107 rows, possibly the code is coping the whole column not just the 107 rows?
no idea on how the fix this

Thanks

```
Sub f()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo Skipit
HeaderNames = Array("RespID", "Subject", "Tag", "Strengths Comments", "Improvement Comments")
For l = 0 To UBound(HeaderNames)
    Columns(Rows(1).Find(HeaderNames(l), , xlValues, xlWhole).Column).Cut
    Columns(l + 1).Insert
Skipit:
Next
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(, l).ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried putting in a break point and stepping through the code? Do you know which iteration of your For loop it is breaking on?

Comment: the mapping goes like this `RespID, Strengths Comments, Improvement Comments, Subject, Tag` to `RespID, Subject, Tag, Strengths Comments, Improvement Comments` the code breaks on `Subject` i.e Subject is cut and pasted then the code stops.  The last two are in there proper positions, so maybe the code is breaking where it is trying to cut and paste into the same column. If so is the a way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not copy and paste in the same place.
this should work:

```
Sub f()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo Skipit
Dim HeaderNames, l As Long, colFrom As Long

HeaderNames = Array("RespID", "Subject", "Tag", "Strengths Comments", "Improvement Comments")
For l = 0 To UBound(HeaderNames)
    colFrom = Rows(1).Find(HeaderNames(l), , xlValues, xlWhole).Column
    If l + 1 <> colFrom Then Columns(colFrom).Cut: Columns(l + 1).Insert
Skipit:
Next
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(, l).ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```